# DC-DC Buck, Selective Voltage Binning (SVB) technique

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I have been trying to understand SVB technique and unable to understand how it is implemented in a DC-DC buck converter as shown in the schematic below. Can someone please explain the SVB circuit part of the below schematics? How does SVB work in the below specific case?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure SVB is an acronym for Selective Voltage Binning nor am I sure that Selective Voltage Binning pertains to this type of circuit.

However, I can tell you what the highlighted circuit does.  The highlighted circuit allows for adjustment (trimming) of the regulated output voltage.  You may find that the voltage at VDD_MEDIA_CORE is monitored by a Micro or something similar.  Based on this the Micro then adjusts the duty cycle of PWM waveform SVB_PWM2_MEDIA.  This in turn affects the feedback voltage feed into the regulator which then causes the regulator to respond and adjust the output voltage.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understood the logic behind the circuit. Could you please explain how this circuit works? I mean, why are there two resistors in series? Is there a formula that explains the circuit in operation? Again, Thank you

Comment: The two resistors, R312 and R313, were likely used as apposed to one resistor to add for greater adjustment in the circuit (think course and fine adjustment).

Comment: The formula, which describes operation, can be derived very simply (but I will leave this to you).  The control voltage, voltage across C314, is simply the duty cycle of the PWM signal multiplied by its on voltage.  The feedback voltage can be quickly derived as the circuit is a two-source voltage divider, the sources being the voltage across C314 and VDD_MEDIA_CORE.